# What can I do in Android Honeycomb for MenuItem.isActionViewExpanded() and MenuItem.collapseActionView()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-menu

The methods MenuItem.isActionViewExpanded() and MenuItem.collapseActionView() were added in Android API version 14 (Ice cream sandwich), so they're not available in Android API versions 11-13 (Honeycomb).  They're the only things that are stopping me from setting my minSdkVersion to 11, so are there any alternatives that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that for me, this question is irrelevant because the installed userbase of honeycomb is so low, see http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html